# Adding object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to subtract the value of object1's objectProperty from object2's object property and I keep getting NaN on the console. Here is example code:

```
    object1.objectProperty - object2.object2Property
```

If this isn't enough to go off, I can post the full code from my project.
If there is another way to do this or some kind of function that can help, please let me know.

edit: Here is the code..

```
    var myPokemon = {
    health: 25,
    defense: 5,
    attack: 10,
    speed: 5
};

var moves = {
    Scratch: 5,
    Bite: 5,
    Slap: 5,
    Growl: 1
};


var computerPokemon = {
    health: 20,
    defense: 5,
    attack: 10, 
    speed: 7
};

function calcDamage(firstPokemon, secondPokemon, move) {
    if(move == moves.Growl){
        //starts here
        var newDefense =  moves.Growl - firstPokemon.defense;
        console.log(newDefense);
        //ends here
    }else{
    var newHealth = (firstPokemon.health + firstPokemon.defense) - (secondPokemon.attack + move);
    console.log(newHealth);
    }
}
```

edit: When I did 
    `moves.Growl - firstPokemon.defense || 0;` it returned -4 instead of NaN which is what I wanted it to do, but the person that answered that removed the answer so this has been answered by whoever that guy was.

Comment: have you checked the values in those properties?

Comment: When getting `NaN`, you most often have an `undefined` variable somewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you tell what is the value of `firstPokemon.defense` when you get NaN

Comment: Your if and else statements have errors, You don't need to use parseInt or Number()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the object in the second argument. Also your if statement will never execute, I have fixed both as following

```js
        var myPokemon = {
     health: 25,
     defense: 5,
     attack: 10,
     speed: 5
    };
    
    var moves = {
     Scratch: 5,
     Bite: 5,
     Slap: 5,
     Growl: 1
    };
    
    
    var computerPokemon = {
     health: 20,
     defense: 5,
     attack: 10, 
     speed: 7
    };
    
    function calcDamage(firstPokemon, secondPokemon, move) {
     if(moves.Growl!=undefined){
            //starts here
      var newDefense =  moves.Growl - firstPokemon.defense;
      alert(newDefense);
            //ends here
     }else{
     var newHealth = (Number(firstPokemon.health) + Number(firstPokemon.defense)) - (Number(secondPokemon.attack) + Number(move.Growl));
     alert(newHealth);
        }
    }

calcDamage(myPokemon,computerPokemon,moves)
```

Comment: also your if statement will not work (moves==moves.Growl) if you wanna check move.Growl exist then do it as moves.Growl!=undefined

Comment: I think he is checking the values of move and moves.Growl. And  not trying to check if it exists are not

Comment: Okay but his if statement was not getting executed and in the else statement he was adding moves instead of a value from it

Comment: @SherKhan I think I found his issue, check my answer

Comment: @ISuckatCPlusPlus let me know if I pointed out your issue right

Comment: @Reddy I already upvoted all the answers including yours, It's move because he is passing he named the third parameter as "move" not "moves", anyways I appreciated your effort, problem is that there are bugs in the code beyond just the NaN problem

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you are getting NaN, you are probably working with other elements but numbers. Are you sure they both are numbers?

Just an example:

```
var x = {}, y = {};
x.r = 10;
y.r = 5;
x.r - y.r; // yields 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)** to convert the values into integer and then do the math.

```
 var value = parseInt(object1.objectProperty,10) - parseInt(object2.object2Property,10);
```

**The Problem is here**

```
var newHealth = (Number(firstPokemon.health) + Number(firstPokemon.defense)) - (Number(secondPokemon.attack) + Number(move.Growl));
```

The last one `Number(move.Growl)` it should be `Number(moves.Growl)`  `moves` not `move`. In your case `move` is just a number and you are trying `Number(move.Growl)`  which will be NaN and hence your getting NaN.

Comment: It's not parseInt problem, problem is that his code was not adding and running conditional statements properly but your answer is good for those who are trying to add strings